# Why can't I set a JavaScript function's name property?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I am learning JavaScript and read that functions are like objects and can have properties set like this:

```
var person = function(){
}
person.name="John Smith"; //output ""
person.age=21; //output 21
person.profession="Web Developer"; //output "Web Developer"
```

Why is the name property blank?

Thanks

Comment: Long story short, it's [one of those quirky things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) you will find in JS.

Comment: I'm amazed that there are so many answers saying you can't do this. It's definitely possible - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41735602/993683

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `name` is a non-standard, **non-writable** [property of function objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Function declarations and [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) are *named*, while you have an anonymous function expression whose `name` is `""`.

You probably wanted a plain object:

```
var person = {
    name: "John Smith",
    age: 21,
    profession: "Web Developer"
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about object literals but needed to understand why I couldn't set a function's name property

Answer (score 5):

`name` is a special property because it gives the name of the function when defined like this:

```
function abc(){

}
```

In this case name would return the string `"abc"`.  This name cannot be changed.  In your case, the function does not have a name, hence the empty string.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xM7G/1/

Answer (score 2):

You **can** change the name property!

The `Function.name` property is `configurable` [as detailed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Since it's configurable, we can alter its `writable` property so it can be changed. We need to use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to do this:

```
var fn = function(){};
Object.defineProperty(fn, "name", {writable:true});
// now you can treat it like a normal property:
fn.name = "hello";
console.log(fn.name); // outputs "hello"
```

Comment: Using this example how would you call the function by hello() instead of fn()?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Prototype (see [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)) or simply turn the 'person' into a hash like so:

```
var person = {};
person.name="John Smith"; //output "John Smith"
person.age=21; //output 21
person.profession="Web Developer"; //output "Web Developer"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.defineProperty` to change the `value` of the property (even without touching its `writeable` flag):

```js
function fn () {}
console.log(fn.name) // Outputs fn

Object.defineProperty(fn, 'name', { value: 'newName' })

console.log(fn.name) // Outputs newName
```

Answer (score -1):

The `name` property is set by the Function constructor and cannot be overwritten directly. If the function is declared anonymous, it will be set to an empty string.

For example:

```
var test = function test() {};
alert(test.name); // Displays "test"
test.name = "test2";
alert(test.name); // Still displays "test"
```

Comment: Actually, `name`, `length` and `prototype` are not inherited but own properties of a function object. Gonna fix MDN :-)