# How can I make "this" refer to the member function and not the instance of its owner class?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.bar = function() {
    this.name = "John"
    console.log("bar's name is " + this.name);
  }
}

var blah = new foo("Peter");
console.log(blah.name);//"Peter"
blah.bar();//"bar's name is John"
console.log(blah.name);//"John"
```

In the example above, how can I make "this", within the function bar, refer to bar, and not its owner, foo?  The desired result would be:

```
var blah = new foo("Peter");
console.log(blah.name);//"Peter"
blah.bar();//"bar's name is John"
console.log(blah.name);//"Peter"
```

Comment: Why would you ever want `this` to refer to a function? Especially since [that wouldn't work any more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18904399/1048572)?

Comment: Afaik, the name property of a function is readonly, so even if you set `this` to the function itself, it wouldn't work. Anyway, this is how you bind `this`: `this.bar = this.bar.bind(this.bar);`. However, I don't see a reason you'd ever want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blah.bar();//"bar's name is John"`
Here you are simply calling the function bar, if you want bar to be it's own object (and have properties like a name), you need to do:
`var bar = new blah.bar();`
This will create the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like you do not want to use `this` at all, but a *local variable* that is not a property of anything:

```
function Foo(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.bar = function bar() {
    var name = "John";
    console.log("the name is " + name);
  }
}

var blah = new Foo("Peter");
console.log(blah.name); // "Peter"
blah.bar();// "the name is John"
console.log(blah.name); // still "Peter"
```

Notice that the [function's `.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) (`blah.bar.name`) is `"bar"` (at least in my example, in your code it was empty) just as `Foo.name` is `"Foo"`, and you even cannot set it.