# How do function-objects fit in the definition of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, language-concepts

I've read that an object is a collection of properties and methods. Then if a function is an object, how do function-objects fit in the definition of objects in JavaScript? **I'm trying to make an example of a Function with properties and functions** but I have any success.

```
 function myperson(){
    this.name= "Bruno";
    personAbility = function(){document.write(1+1);};
}

document.write(myperson.name);
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should have this.personAbility to have static acccess to the function as well.

Comment: Apart from `this` not refering to the `myperson` function (and you never executing that code), have a look at [Why can't I set a JavaScript function's name property?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18904399/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating instance of `myperson` in your code.

As you said, functions are objects. Yes, functions are objects and they have properties too. When you are saying `myperson.name` you are actually accessing the function's name field.

Since it is a function and it is [named function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), the name of the function is **myperson** which you had declared for the function and this is handled by Javascript engine.

Also, `this` inside the function points to `window` object because you are not invoking the function as constructor or binding to any object. So just calling the function will not set `myperson.name` attribute, you need to use `new` operator like `new myperson` and create an object and that object will have the property "name" which you want to access.

---

```
function myperson() {
    this.name= "Bruno";
    this.personAbility = function(){document.write(1+1);};
}

var per = new myperson();
document.write(per.otherName);
//call the personAbility method like below
per.personAbility();
```

More about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm trying to call the method inside i.e. personAbility with    <per.personAbility;>     but it doesn't show anything and it's supposed to print the number 2. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Update my answer, as you asked. adding this before personAbility will make member of that class. now you can access `per.personAbility()` function.

Comment: Yuhu, yes it works! Thanks a lot :) Is this the only way to declare properties and methos inside a method?

Comment: Nope. There are many other ways. If you are interested go through this series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB or read Douglas Crockford book.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, you just need to instantiate your myperson object. You can do this by writing `var myPerson = new myperson()`. Then, `console.log(myPerson)` should display:
`myperson {name: "Bruno"}`

To go along with your `document.write` example, you could do `document.write(myPerson.name)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword will become available once you treat your function as a constructor function, meaning that you have to create a new instace by using the `new` keyword:

```
function myperson(){
    this.name= "Bruno";
    personAbility = function(){document.write(1+1);};
}

var person = new myperson();
document.write(person.name);
```